If vs when, in condition clause
When I were younger, I never learned to play a musical instrument. And now I think it would be helpfull to play a guitar to relieve stress. In this situatiom, I would like to say..
If I had learned to play guitar,

1.I would play guitar when I stress out


2.I would play guitar if I stressed out

I would like to know the difference and which is right.

I play the guitar (if I need) to relax.

Something might stress me out, or I could be stressed out as an adjectival usage, but I can't be doing with intransitive to stress out. But if I did, then in the past tense #1 above it would have to be I would play guitar when I stressed out. (... was / felt / became stressed out in my version of English! :)

When I was younger.

I. Mixed Conditional Sentence
OP has enquired about the difference between using "if" and "when" in a Mixed Conditional Sentence :


If I had learned to play guitar, I would play guitar when I am stressed out.
If I had learned to play guitar, I would play guitar if I am stressed out.


These sentences involve a past hypothetical situation (a change in the past) with a result in the present, making them Mixed Conditionals. (the "if" clause is a Third Conditional, and the main clause is a Second Conditional).

Reference British Council:.
Mixed conditionals: Past/Present.
Here's a sentence imagining how a change in a past situation would have a result in the present.
If I hadn't got the job in Tokyo, I wouldn't be with my current partner.

II. Difference between "when" and "if" - Certainty vs. Possibility:

I would like to know the difference and which is right.

Both sentences are grammatically correct, but the difference lies in how "when" and "if" are used to express certainty or possibility about stress.
Sentence 1:.
"When I am stressed out" implies certainty. It assumes that stress will definitely happen in the future, making it a regular or predictable part of life.
Sentence 2:.
"If I am stressed out" introduces possibility. It suggests that stress may or may not happen in the future, treating it as a less certain event.
III. Playing Guitar for Stress relief:
Use Sentence 1 if you see stress as a regular, predictable part of your life, and playing guitar would be a consistent way of coping.
Use Sentence 2 if stress is less predictable, and you would only play guitar in specific situations when you are stressed.
